# What does the symbol $f_n \uparrow f$ mean?

Tags: measure-theory

What does the symbol  $f_n \uparrow f$ in measure theory mean?

Comment: It might mean that the sequence $f_n$ is increasing, and has the limit $f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f_n$ is a sequence of functions that is pointwise increasing to $f$, i.e. for each $x$ in the domain of $f$, $f_{n}(x)<f_{n+1}(x)$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: What is " pointwise increasing to $f$ "?

Comment: @NZhang: Read the version that's currently up. It gives the definition.

Comment: Also, instead of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x) = f(x)$, one can say that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}f_n(x) = f(x)$.