# What does $f_n\nearrow f$ mean?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_n, f$ be non-negative measurable functions?

What exactly is meant with $f_n\nearrow f$?

Does that mean $f_n\leq f_{n+1}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=f$?

Or $\sup_{n}f_n=f$?

Comment: I've usually seen it meaning the former, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=f$ and $f_n \leq f_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Comment: Since the sequence is increasing then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = \sup_{n} f_n = f$.

Comment: See [What does the symbol $f_n \uparrow f$ mean?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/342464/264)

Comment: @Bunder Why is $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=\sup_n f_n=f$ when the sequence $(f_n)$ increases?

Comment: Any increasing sequence that converges has its supremum as its limit. It is a little exercise to prove it.